# Update version properties during Maven release prepare

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

How do I update properties during a `mvn release:prepare`

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.proj</groupId>
  <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <proj-dependency-version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</proj-dependency-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>my.proj.dependency</groupId>
      <artifactId>proj-dependency</artifactId>
      <version>${proj-dependency-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: what do you mean update? What is your desired output?

Comment: The dependency should get updated from 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT to release 1.0.0

Comment: Which one you would like to release? my.proj.dependency:proj-dpendency or com.mycompany.proj:mavenproject1 ?

Comment: I want to perform mvn release on com.mycompany.proj:mavenproject1.
The mvn release has already been run for my.proj.dependency:proj-dpendency whihc is now at 1.0.0. 

During the mvn release of com.mycompany.proj:mavenproject1 I want its dependency to be updated to use the latest release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution via the maven version:update_properties plugin